# Misconfigured model problem

Tags: magento-1.9, module, setup

I'm very new to Magento, and working through some tutorials.

I am trying to setup a new Model, and, without created a Model file first, tried to access it to make sure that it was configured correctly.

I received the error `Warning: include(Mage\Complex\Model\Complexpost.php)` instead of `Warning: include(Eav\Complex\Model\Complexpost.php)`, which I was expecting.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
app
  code
    local
      Eav
        Complex
          Block
          controllers
            IndexController.php
          etc
            config.xml
          Helper
          Model
          sql
```

I have also created the file `app/etc/modules/Eav_Complex.xml` with the content

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eav_Complex>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Eav_Complex>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The `IndexController.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
class Eav_Complex_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $complex = Mage::getModel("complex/complexpost");
        var_dump($complex);
    }
}
```

and my config looks like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eav_Complex>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Eav_Complex>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <complex>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Eav_Complex</module>
                    <frontName>complex</frontName>
                </args>
            </complex>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <complex>
                <class>Eav_Complex_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>complex_resource</resourceModel>
            </complex>

            <complex_resource>
                <class>Eav_Complex_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <complexpost>
                        <table>complex_post</table>
                    </complexpost>
                </entities>
            </complex_resource>
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

The URL I was trying to access was `http://127.0.0.1/magento1/complex` (I have already made a HelloWorld module, which worked, so I'm sure that the URL is correct).

Can anyone see anything obviously out of place? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it seams like you are doing it right. Did you clear the cache? Do you have an other module that has `complex` as a subtag of `<models>` in `config.xml` ?

Comment: @Marius *DAMNIT* - clearing the cache worked... I've been doing this for 2 days and I still forget to clear my cache :( Thank you! If you post your comment as an answer, I will gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Skytiger I highly recommend disabling the cache during development to avoid this sort of issue.

Comment: @JosephLeedy Thanks, I did that shortly after this fiasco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can happen for 2 reasons (at least that's how many I know):

- You did not clear the cache.
- you have an other module that uses the key `complex` for model aliases

Comment: Thanks Marius, in this case it was the (silly) problem of a cache not being cleared :)