# Invalid entity_type specified

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, setup

I am working through some [tutorials](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-7.html) and have become stuck.

My setup so far is as follows:

*folder structure*

```
app
  code
    local
      Eav
        Complex
          Block
          controllers
            IndexController.php
          etc
            config.xml
          Helper
          Model
            Resource
              Complexpost.php
              Setup.php
            Complexpost.php
          sql
            complex_setup
              install-0.1.0.php
```

*app/etc/modules/Eav_Complex.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eav_Complex>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Eav_Complex>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*IndexController.php*

```
<?php
class Eav_Complex_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $complex = Mage::getModel("complex/complexpost");
        var_dump($complex);
    }
}
```

*config.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eav_Complex>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Eav_Complex>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <complex>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Eav_Complex</module>
                    <frontName>complex</frontName>
                </args>
            </complex>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <complex>
                <class>Eav_Complex_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>complex_resource</resourceModel>
            </complex>

            <complex_resource>
                <class>Eav_Complex_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <complexpost>
                        <table>complex_post</table>
                    </complexpost>
                </entities>
            </complex_resource>
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

[All the above files are correct - I have already asked a question earlier about them.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105183/misconfigured-model-problem), so up until here I know everything is in order.

I'm fairly certain that the following files are also in order, and that the problem lies elsewhere, but just to be safe I am posting them here as well.

*Model/Complexpost.php*

```
<?php
class Eav_Complex_Model_Complexpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("complex/complexpost");
    }
}
```

*Model/Resource/Complexpost.php*

```
<?php
class Eav_Complex_Model_Resource_Complexpost extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType("complex_complexpost");
        $this->getConnection(
            $this->setConnection("complex_read"),
            $this->setConenctION("complex_write")
        );
    }
}
```

*Model/Resource/Setup.php*

```
<?php
class Eav_Complex_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{

}
```

*install-0.1.0.php*

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
throw new Exception("Stopping installer from completing");
```

When I hit the URL `http://127.0.0.1/magento1/complex` (I have confirmed that the URL is correct), I receive this error message: `Invalid entity_type specified: complex_complexpost` - This seems to complain that the resource type in `Model/Resource/Complexpost.php` is incorrect.

I have not set up anything in the database either via phpAdmin or via installer - could that potentially be the problem?

I am expecting an exception at this point, but the one I am expecting is the one that I thrown manually in `install-0.1.0.php`, not the one I'm getting.

If you can see anything obviously out of place, I'd be very grateful if you could point it out, and even more so if you could explain what my mistake was (I am still learning Magento and understanding my mistake would be super helpful!)

Comment: are you trying to create an EAV entity (like products or categories) or a flat one (with one table associated to it)?

Comment: Definitely an EAV entity. I've already created a flat one as a previous part of the tutorial.

Comment: Then take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/22367/146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create an EAV entity, you need a record for that entity in the `eav_entity_type` table.
This needs to be inserted when the module is installed.
For this you need to make your `install-0.1.0.php` look like this:

```
<?php 
//you might want to create tables here also
$this->installEntities();
```

your `config.xml` should contain this under the `global` tag

```
    <resources>
        <complex_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Eav_Complex</module>
                <class>Eav_Complex_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </complex_setup>
    </resources>
```

and your class `Eav_Complex_Model_Resource_Setup` should contain this method:

```
public function getDefaultEntities(){
    $entities = array();
    $entities['complex_complexpost'] = array(
            'entity_model'                  => 'complex/complexpost',
            'attribute_model'               => 'complex/resource_eav_attribute', //this might not be needed
            'table'                         => 'complex/complexpost', //might not be needed
            'additional_attribute_table'    => 'complex/eav_attribute', //might not be needed
            'entity_attribute_collection'   => 'complex/complex_attribute_collection',
            'attributes'        => array( //list here all your entity attributes
                    'title' => array(
                        'group'          => 'General',
                        'type'           => 'varchar',
                        'backend'        => '',
                        'frontend'       => '',
                        'label'          => 'Title',
                        'input'          => 'text',
                        'source'         => '',
                        'global'         => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'required'       => '1',
                        'user_defined'   => false,
                        'default'        => '',
                        'unique'         => false,
                        'position'       => '10',
                        'note'           => '',
                        'visible'        => '1',
                        'wysiwyg_enabled'=> '0',
                    ),
             ),
         );
     return $entities;
}
```

I hope I've closed all the brackets and parentheses.
You will end up with a bunch of new errors after this because you have a log of files still missing, but it should solve your entity type problem.
For a full description on how to create an eav entity, check this question: [How to create an EAV entity?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/how-to-create-an-eav-entity)

Comment: I read your other post and this answer and it's *really* helped and cleared some things up for me! I haven't found any example of an EAV entity anywhere else thats near as descriptive. Thanks, I really appreciate it.